# Powershell - Help to wrap script in GUI

Tags: forms, user-interface, powershell

I want to wrap an existing powershell script I've created in to a GUI but without sending days on it trying to figure it out I thought I post here. I have created a from in Primal forms for what the script should look like but need assistance in coverting it.

The script I run adds computer accounts to a security group given 3 options. Run the script against the localhost, a list of computers or manually entering the hostname. Additionally I'd like to select a group and act on the selection rather than entering the group name manually if possible.

**My main script**

```
   Import-Module ActiveDirectory
   cls
   $OU = "OU=TESTScripts,OU=Groups,OU=Company,DC=Company,DC=local"
   $AppGroupList = Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq "security"} -SearchBase "$OU"
   $AppGroupList | Select-Object @{Name="AD Security Group";Expression={$_.Name}}

   $title = "Add manually entered computer, localhost or list of computers to SCCM        Application Install Group"
   $message = "Please select an option from below:-"

   $1 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "Enter &Hostname"

   $2 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "Add &List of Computers"

   $3 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Add localhost"

   $options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($1, $2, $3)
   $result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0)


switch ($result)
    {
        0 {$Computers = Read-Host "Enter Hostname>"}                          

        1 {$Computers = get-content "c:\scripts\Computers.csv"}                   

        2 {$Computers = $env:computername}

    }

    $AppGroup = Read-Host "Application Security Group Name>"
    $Group = Get-ADGroup -Identity $AppGroup     

 foreach ($Hostname in $Computers){

        $member = Get-ADComputer -Identity "$Hostname" -Properties MemberOf | Select-Object MemberOf
        $pc = Get-ADComputer "$Hostname"

            if ($member.Memberof -like "$Group"){
                Write-Host ""   
                Write-Host $Hostname is already a member of $AppGroup -ForegroundColor "Yellow"     
            }

            else {
                Add-ADGroupMember $AppGroup $pc
                Write-Host ""
                Write-Host $Hostname has been added to $AppGroup -ForegroundColor "Green"   


            }
}
```

`

**My form code looks like this:-**

```
    #Generated Form Function
    function GenerateForm {
    ########################################################################
    # Code Generated By: SAPIEN Technologies PrimalForms (Community Edition) v1.0.10.0
    # Generated On: 22/03/2013 11:17 AM
    ########################################################################

    #region Import the Assemblies
    [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
    [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
    #endregion

    #region Generated Form Objects
    $form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Hostname = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Hostname = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $Install = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $Browse = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $checkBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    $ListApps = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
    #endregion Generated Form Objects

    #----------------------------------------------
    #Generated Event Script Blocks
    #----------------------------------------------
    #Provide Custom Code for events specified in PrimalForms.
    $handler_textBox1_TextChanged= 
    {
    #TODO: Place custom script here

    }

    $Browse_OnClick= 
    {
    #TODO: Place custom script here

    }

    $handler_label2_Click= 
    {
    #TODO: Place custom script here

    }

    $handler_form1_Load= 
    {
    #TODO: Place custom script here

    Import-Module ActiveDirectory

    $OU = "OU=TESTScripts,OU=Groups,OU=Company,DC=Company,DC=local"
    $AppGroupList = Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq "security"} -SearchBase "$OU"
    $AppGroupList | Select-Object @{Name="AD Security Group";Expression={$_.Name}}


    }

    $Install_OnClick= 
    {
    #TODO: Place custom script here

    }

    $handler_checkBox1_CheckedChanged= 
    {
    #TODO: Place custom script here

    }

    $OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
    {#Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
$form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
    }

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Form Code
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 423
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 284
    $form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
    $form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $form1.Name = "form1"
    $form1.Text = "Install Software"
    $form1.add_Load($handler_form1_Load)

    $label3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 12
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 76
    $label3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $label3.Name = "label3"
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 20
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 185
    $label3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $label3.TabIndex = 7
    $label3.Text = "Application Install Groups:-"

    $form1.Controls.Add($label3)

    $Hostname.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 206
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 146
    $Hostname.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $Hostname.Name = "Hostname"
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 29
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 66
    $Hostname.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Hostname.TabIndex = 6
    $Hostname.Text = "Enter Hostname"
    $Hostname.add_Click($handler_label2_Click)

    $form1.Controls.Add($Hostname)

    $Hostname.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 91
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 155
    $Hostname.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $Hostname.Name = "Hostname"
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 20
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 102
    $Hostname.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Hostname.TabIndex = 5
    $Hostname.add_TextChanged($handler_textBox1_TextChanged)

    $form1.Controls.Add($Hostname)


    $Install.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 10
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 246
    $Install.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $Install.Name = "Install"
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 38
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 259
    $Install.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Install.TabIndex = 4
    $Install.Text = "Install"
    $Install.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $Install.add_Click($Install_OnClick)

    $form1.Controls.Add($Install)

    $label1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 91
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 206
    $label1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $label1.Name = "label1"
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 18
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 164
    $label1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $label1.TabIndex = 3
    $label1.Text = "Browse to add list of computers"

    $form1.Controls.Add($label1)


    $Browse.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 10
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 201
    $Browse.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $Browse.Name = "Browse"
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 75
    $Browse.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Browse.TabIndex = 2
    $Browse.Text = "Browse"
    $Browse.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $Browse.add_Click($Browse_OnClick)

    $form1.Controls.Add($Browse)


    $checkBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 12
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 135
    $checkBox1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1"
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 60
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 75
    $checkBox1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $checkBox1.TabIndex = 1
    $checkBox1.Text = "Tick LocalHost"
    $checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $checkBox1.add_CheckedChanged($handler_checkBox1_CheckedChanged)

    $form1.Controls.Add($checkBox1)

    $ListApps.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $ListApps.FormattingEnabled = $True
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 12
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 108
    $ListApps.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $ListApps.Name = "ListApps"
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 21
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 260
    $ListApps.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $ListApps.TabIndex = 0

    $form1.Controls.Add($ListApps)

    #endregion Generated Form Code

    #Save the initial state of the form
    $InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
    #Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
    $form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
    #Show the Form
    $form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

    } #End Function

    #Call the Function
    GenerateForm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the complete code for converting the above script into a GUI.**

```
#Generated Form Function
function GenerateForm {
########################################################################
# Code Generated By: SAPIEN Technologies PrimalForms (Community Edition) v1.0.10.0
# Generated On: 25/03/2013 4:56 PM
# Generated By: MrMeaner
########################################################################

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#region Import the Assemblies
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
#endregion

#region Generated Form Objects
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$radioButton3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$radioButton2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$radioButton1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$textHostname = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$txtHostname = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Install = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Browse = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ListApps = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
#endregion Generated Form Objects

#----------------------------------------------
#Generated Event Script Blocks
#----------------------------------------------
#Provide Custom Code for events.

$Browse_OnClick= 
{
#When Browse button is clicked
$FileName = Select-FileDialog
$Computers = Get-Content $FileName
$Install.enabled = $true

}

$Install_OnClick= 
{
#Add computer to security group script

    if (!$ListApps.SelectedItem) {[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please select an SCCM application install group name from the drop down menu")

       }
    else {

        $AppGroup = $ListApps.SelectedItem.ToString()

        $Group = Get-ADGroup -Identity $AppGroup 

            foreach ($Hostname in $Computers){

                $member = Get-ADComputer -Identity "$Hostname" -Properties MemberOf | Select-Object MemberOf
                $pc = Get-ADComputer "$Hostname"

                if ($member.Memberof -like "$Group"){
                    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$Hostname is already a member of $AppGroup")     
                }

                else {
                    Add-ADGroupMember $AppGroup $pc
                    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$Hostname has been added to $AppGroup")  

                }
            }  
    }

}

$handler_radioButton1_CheckedChanged= 
{
#Localhost radio button
$txtHostname.enabled = $false
$Browse.enabled = $false
$Computers = $env:computername
$Install.enabled = $true

}

$handler_radioButton2_CheckedChanged= 
{
#Enter Hostname radiobutton
$txtHostname.enabled = $true
$Browse.enabled = $false
}

$handler_radioButton3_CheckedChanged= 
{
#Load list of computers radiobutton
$Browse.enabled = $true
$txtHostname.enabled = $false

}

$handler_textBox1_TextChanged= 
{
#Hostname textbox
$Computers = $txtHostname.Text.ToString()
$Install.enabled = $true

}

$handler_form1_Load= 
{
#Runs when script is loaded

$Install.enabled = $false
$OU = "OU=TESTScripts,OU=Groups,OU=Company,DC=Company,DC=local"
$AppGroupList = Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq "security"} -SearchBase "$OU" | Select -expand Name


#Fill the list with the groupnames  
$AppGroupList | % { $ListApps.Items.Add($_) }
}


$OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
{#Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 271
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 284
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.Text = "Install Software"
$form1.add_Load($handler_form1_Load)


$radioButton3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 188
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 58
$radioButton3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$radioButton3.Name = "radioButton3"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 51
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 88
$radioButton3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$radioButton3.TabIndex = 10
$radioButton3.TabStop = $True
$radioButton3.Text = "Load List of Computers"
$radioButton3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$radioButton3.add_CheckedChanged($handler_radioButton3_CheckedChanged)

$form1.Controls.Add($radioButton3)


$radioButton2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 102
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 54
$radioButton2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$radioButton2.Name = "radioButton2"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 58
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 80
$radioButton2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$radioButton2.TabIndex = 9
$radioButton2.TabStop = $True
$radioButton2.Text = "Enter Hostname"
$radioButton2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$radioButton2.add_CheckedChanged($handler_radioButton2_CheckedChanged)

$form1.Controls.Add($radioButton2)


$radioButton1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 7
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 59
$radioButton1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$radioButton1.Name = "radioButton1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 48
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 76
$radioButton1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$radioButton1.TabIndex = 8
$radioButton1.TabStop = $True
$radioButton1.Text = "LocalHost"
$radioButton1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$radioButton1.add_CheckedChanged($handler_radioButton1_CheckedChanged)

$form1.Controls.Add($radioButton1)

$label3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 7
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 9
$label3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$label3.Name = "label3"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 20
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 185
$label3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$label3.TabIndex = 7
$label3.Text = "SCCM Application Install Groups:-"

$form1.Controls.Add($label3)

$textHostname.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 140
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 113
$textHostname.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$textHostname.Name = "textHostname"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 27
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 105
$textHostname.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$textHostname.TabIndex = 6
$textHostname.Text = "Enter Hostname"
$textHostname.add_Click($handler_label2_Click)

$form1.Controls.Add($textHostname)

$txtHostname.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 7
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 113
$txtHostname.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$txtHostname.Name = "txtHostname"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 20
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 124
$txtHostname.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$txtHostname.TabIndex = 5
$txtHostname.add_Leave($handler_textBox1_TextChanged)

$form1.Controls.Add($txtHostname)


$Install.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 7
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 181
$Install.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$Install.Name = "Install"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 82
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 269
$Install.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$Install.TabIndex = 4
$Install.Text = "Install"
$Install.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$Install.add_Click($Install_OnClick)

$form1.Controls.Add($Install)

$label1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 140
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 155
$label1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$label1.Name = "label1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 115
$label1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$label1.TabIndex = 3
$label1.Text = "Load computer list"

$form1.Controls.Add($label1)


$Browse.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 7
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 150
$Browse.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$Browse.Name = "Browse"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 124
$Browse.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$Browse.TabIndex = 2
$Browse.Text = "Browse"
$Browse.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$Browse.add_Click($Browse_OnClick)

$form1.Controls.Add($Browse)

$ListApps.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$ListApps.FormattingEnabled = $True
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 7
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 32
$ListApps.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$ListApps.Name = "ListApps"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 21
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 269
$ListApps.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$ListApps.TabIndex = 0

$form1.Controls.Add($ListApps)

#endregion Generated Form Code

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

} #End Function


#Select File Explorer Function
function Select-FileDialog {

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$ofd = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$ofd.InitialDirectory = "d:\scripts"
$ofd.ShowHelp=$true
if($ofd.ShowDialog() -eq "OK") { $ofd.FileName }

} #End Function


#Call the Function
GenerateForm
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is too wide. Please ask for a specific problem and try yourself. If you know basic powerhsell and/or basic c# you will come further. To help you populate the app groups list as you specifically wanted, try:

```
$handler_form1_Load= 
{
#TODO: Place custom script here
#I would move this import line out of the form and to the top of the script 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$OU = "OU=TESTScripts,OU=Groups,OU=Metro Trains,DC=Metrotrains,DC=local"
$AppGroupList = Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq "security"} -SearchBase "$OU" | Select -expand Name

#Fill the list with the groupnames  
$AppGroupList | % { $ListApps.Items.Add($_) }

}
```

You should look into disabling some of the controls when one is used. Ex. if the localhost checkbox is checked, disable the textbox and the browse-button (if you don't need to ability to use all three). Add a `click` eventhandler to the Install-button that takes the current values from the form and runs the "add computer to group"-code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand it's a broad question, I've never created a GUI for my scripts before and this is my first. How would I go about taking the selected group value from the Apps list? I'm getting an error in the script on the Add-ADGroupMember. I guess it's because it's not passing the selected value to the $AppGroup variable because it's not defined anywhere.

Comment: Nevermind I added the line: $AppGroup = $ListApps.SelectedItem.ToString() to the top $Install_OnClick

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I changed the layout a bit and took on your advise and disabled some of the controls using radio buttons. I've completed the script and posted the complete code here for others to benifit from:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627293/add-computers-to-security-groups-powershell-gui-complete-code

Answer (score 0):

I'm no good when it comes to the Windows Presentation Foundation stuff or WinForms. I like it when PowerShell takes care of me. I hope this is something you can use:

```
$OU = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * | Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Choose OU'
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had a play around with Out-GridView yesterday but unfortunately it doesn't help. Cheers.